# How can I ensure that an if else statement works only if the exact condition is true in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an if/else statement that returns an image if the chicken checkbox is checked, however, if you check the chicken checkbox and another one it still displays the image, how can I set the statement to only display the image only if the chicken checkbox is checked?

The code is as follows:

```
if (chicken.checked == true) {
  document.getElementById("image").style.visibility = "visible";
} else {  
  return document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "*Please mark any of checkbox";  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, in this example, the image is hidden. [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (`filter` returns an array so you can check its length) on the checked boxes. If the length of the checked boxes is 1, *and* it's the chicken box, remove the hidden class from the image, otherwise add it back.

Note: the reason I've added a click listener to the container, and haven't added one to each checkbox is to take advantage of [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). The container catches the events from the boxes as they bubble up the DOM. That's why we need to check that the element that's been clicked on is an input (using `nodeName`).

```js
// Cache some elements
const chicken = document.querySelector('#chicken');
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

// Add a listener to the container
container.addEventListener('click', handleBox, false);

function handleBox(e) {

  // Extract the nodeName, and the name of the
  // element that's been checked
  const { nodeName, name } = e.target;

  // If it's an input
  if (nodeName === 'INPUT') {

    // `filter` on the checked boxes
    // `[...boxes]` means convert the nodelist
    // (which doesn't have array methods)
    // to an array, so we can use `filter`
    const checkedBoxes = [...boxes].filter(box => box.checked);

    // If the number of checked boxes is 1,
    // and it's the chicken box...
    if (checkedBoxes.length === 1 && checkedBoxes[0].name === 'chicken') {

      // ...remove the hidden class from the chicken div...
      chicken.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {

      // ...otherwise add the hidden class back
      chicken.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input name="chicken" type="checkbox">
  <label>Chicken</label><br/>
  <input name="mongoose" type="checkbox">
  <label>Mongoose</label><br/>
  <input name="steve" type="checkbox">
  <label>Steve</label><br/>
  <input name="kookaburra" type="checkbox">
  <label>Kookaburra</label><br/>
</div>
<br />
<div id="chicken" class="hidden">Chicken image</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the Image only when chicken checkbox is checked , then you should probably test all other checkbox's value in the if/else statement.